# Limit to download images from Open Access Hub

Tags: sentinel-2, copernicus, esa

I am running a code https://github.com/diogocaribe/harpia/blob/dev/app/SentinelDownloadTile.py to download all files of Sentinel 2 from my area of interest. However, now a days the download doesn't work but the code is the same. Is there limitation of how many files we can get from Open Access Hub?

Comment: Problem happened in Esa server.

Answer (score 1):

There is a limitation with how many images you can download at a time. This is 2. But i don't believe there is a limitation overall.

However, if you're using Python, try the "sentinelsat" API.

Example code follows:

```
#First, import this library (sentinelsat)
from sentinelsat import SentinelAPI, read_geojson, geojson_to_wkt
from datetime import date

api = SentinelAPI('user', 'password', 'https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus')

# search by polygon, time, and SciHub query keywords
footprint = geojson_to_wkt(read_geojson(r'/path/to/map.geojson'))
products = api.query(footprint,
                     date=('20151219', date(2015, 12, 29)),
                     platformname='Sentinel-2',
                     cloudcoverpercentage=(0, 30))

#Download all products 
api.download_all(products)
```

FYI, if you're looking for countrywide data, split the AOI up into smaller shapefiles as i had this issue where it returned no results when my AOI was too large.

Have a read of this for more info:
https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/sentinelsat/master/sentinelsat.pdf

There are also options for Sentinel-1 batch download too.

Thanks,

Comment: There was a problem in ESA server that many people in the world couldn't download images.